# Setting Highcharts piechart chartDefaults from calling jsx file in React

Tags: javascript, highcharts, reactjs

I am using the following syntax to render a Highcharts PieChart.

```
var ContainingClass = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <PieChart
            title={this.props.title}
            series={this.props.series}
        />
    );
  },
});
```

This works well, but I need to overwrite the `tooltip` field in `PieChart`.  What can I change in `ContainingClass` to make this happen?

Edit: Here is a sample fiddle with `PieChart` - http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/ I know that I need to set the tooltip field and could do it in plain javascript or jquery. I don't know how to pass my desired `tooltip` value from `ContainingClass` in React.

Comment: Where did the `PieChart` component come from? Does it have documentation, or could you look at the source code to answer your question?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, here is a sample fiddle with `PieChart` - http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/  I know that I need to set the `tooltip` field and could do it in plain javascript or jquery.  I don't know how to pass my desired `tooltip` value from `ContainingClass` in React.

Comment: But where does the React component called `PieChart` come from? The example you linked is jQuery.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Here is a pastie with `PieChart.jsx`  It's just a `.jsx` wrapper around a jQuery version of PieChart: http://pastie.org/private/mhixvhkg1j5stgrflqlurg

Comment: Is the tooltip you want exposed in the code or in the mixin code you didn't include? You may need to add it.

Comment: The tooltip is in `PieChart.jsx`.  By default, it is set to `tooltip: {
        percentageDecimals: 1,
      },` and I want to add a few more fields to that hash.

Comment: More specifically, I want to add them by passing them to `PieChart.jsx` from `ContainingClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to pass a `ChartOverride` function as follows:

```
var ContainingClass = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
        <PieChart
            title={this.props.name}
            series={this.props.series}
            chartOverrides={this.chartOverrides()}
        />
    );
  },
  chartOverrides: function() {
    return {
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
    }
  }

});
```